# Mysql query to get latest data using date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, aggregate-functions

[image]

This is my table. Now i have to find out the latest company_name of each user_id. The fact is that, if exp_to is null then it will be considered latest, or if both exp_from & exp_to are not null then i have to find the latest company name using exp_to date. Note that, user_id is appearing multiple times in the given table.

Here is what i want:

```
id | company_name 
-----------------
14 | Deltalife Insurance Company Ltd.
1  | Orbital Software
25 | MMTV    
18 | Noakhali Science & Technology University
```

and so on.....
How can i do it with mysql? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the primary key in your table?

Comment: it is id, which is auto increment

Comment: If you can provide create table and example insert statements, we can give it a try

Comment: if id is primary key , how it is possible to insert same value against primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward aggregation problem. As you have likely figured out, nulls cause [some interesting behavior](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) in SQL. You can use CASE WHEN to check for null and replace with a different value.

In your case:

```
SELECT 
  data.* 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    *,
    CASE WHEN exp_to is null THEN 1 ELSE exp_to END max_date
  FROM your_table
) data
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    CASE WHEN MAX(exp_to is null) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE MAX(exp_to) END max_date
  FROM
    your_table
  GROUP BY user_id
) j
ON data.user_id = j.user_id AND data.max_date = j.max_date
```

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: That is what i am looking for !! I got my desired result....Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Good luck! As a side note, be sure to do some reading on inner join and case when.

Answer (score 1):

With whatever information you have provided, I can figure-out this query

```
Select * from Table_Name where exp_to = null || exp_to = (select max(exp_to) from Table_Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an application for the *structured* part of Structured query language.

First, you need to know which date is the latest for each `user_id`.  This subquery yields that information:

```
       SELECT user_id,
              MAX(IFNULL(NOW(), exp_to) exp_to
         FROM mytable
        GROUP BY user_id
```

Then, you need to use that result to find the company, by joining it to your table.

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.company_name
  FROM mytable a
  JOIN (
            SELECT user_id,
                   MAX(IFNULL(NOW(), exp_to) exp_to
              FROM mytable
             GROUP BY user_id
       ) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND IFNULL(NOW(), a.exp_to) = b.exp_to
```

That should locate the company name associated with the most recent `exp_to` for each `user_id`.  `IFNULL(NOW(),exp_to)` implements your requirement that a NULL date be considered as if it were the present time.

This query is an example of a general pattern of queries: Find the rows with extreme (max,min) values of a particular values.